# Zebra RW420 CPCL font issue

Tags: android, zebra-printers

I've designed a label with Label Vista (free Zebra software) and I went  watching at the generated CPCL code, I noticed:

```
_TTF -23 0 0 400 0 0 0 0 2 34 [Arial] 117 16 Test TTF string
T Ari06pt.cpf 0 118 45 Test Uploaded font string
```

I've uploaded to the printer the Ari06pt.cpf generated font.
Then I've tried to print from Label Vista and all went OK! IT WORKS!

After that I've passed the code to my android application (JAVA with Zebra SDK) and I've tried to print, but in this case only the

```
"T Ari06pt.cpf 0 118 45 Test Uploaded font string\r\n"
```

works right.... the first line (_TTF) is NOT WORKING anymore (white line was printed)...

Some solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [CPCL manual](http://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/printer/cpcl-pm-en.pdf):

```
_TTF -23 0 0 400 0 0 0 0 2 34 [Arial] 117 16 Test TTF string
```

is not a CPCL command. However, LabelVista creates for some reason (??) this command using resident TrueType fonts of your desktop OS and converts it silently in printing time to a CPCL "T" command like that:

```
T Ari06pt.cpf 0 117 16 Test TTF string
```

So I think that you should check LabelVista output if it contains commands other than CPCL. You can also try ZebraDesigner editor.

I have worked with Zebra MZ320 and QL420+ and they accept only prescaled fonts (*.cpf files) in their memory. **So try to convert a TrueType font to a prescaled font**. You can convert it using LabelVista or Zebra Font Downloader and then upload it to your printer. You can follow [this Zebra font convertion guide](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO7889).